# matrix congruence and smith normal form

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

Fixed $n \geq 2$ and consider $A,B \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z}).$ We know that we have [the Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form). One can find $U, V \in SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $A=UDV.$ So as $B$. The Smith normal form is easy to compute by using Mathematica.

We also define Two matrices $A,B$ are congruent if there exists $X \in PSL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $X^TAX=B$. One can see the related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800488/existence-of-unimodular-congruence-transformation-for-symmetric-integer-matrice) here.

Now we have the following, if two matrices are congruent, then they have the same $D$. But now I want to ask is that I have two 4 by 4 matrices. I have checked they have the same $D$ in the smith normal form. But how do I know how to verify they are congruent. If it is, I have to find such $X.$

To be more specific, suppose $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right), B=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 4 & -6 & 4 & -2 \\
 -6 & 12 & -8 & 4 \\
 4 & -8 & 6 & -3 \\
 -2 & 4 & -3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right).$ I want to ask whether $A,B$ are congruent. I listed what I already tried.

1. $A$, $B$ both have the same $D=\left(
   \begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
   \end{array}
   \right)$ in the smith normal form. So they define the same integer lattices. But I do not know whether they are congruent.
2. Both of them have 4 positive eigenvalues. So [Sylvester theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) show that they are real congruent. But may not be integer congruent.
3. I try to use Mathematica to find $X$ but it cost a lot.

I suspect that they are congruent but I do have an idea on how to solve them. Any ideas or comments are really appreciated. Btw, $A$ is the Cartanf matrix of $SO(8).$ I think it will not help.

Comment: You just want to check if two define lattices are properly isometric. Any modern computer algebra system can do this, e.g. Sage or Magma.

Comment: @hans, thanks, I will check them.

Comment: @hans, I have checked this [quadratic form](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/quadratic_forms/sage/quadratic_forms/quadratic_form.html#sage.quadratic_forms.quadratic_form.quadratic_form_from_invariants). I think this is what I want.

Comment: But I found that "is_rationally_isometric" function only works for number field but not integers

Comment: A back-of-the-envelope calculation seems to indicate these two forms have different 3-adic Hasse-Witt invariants, which would mean that they are not isomorphic over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @TylerLawson, but I have used the sage. It seams like they are isomorphic over Q. But I am not sure it is isomorphic over Z. Let me check the invariant of what you mentioned.

Comment: My apologies, I obviously made a mistake in the calculation.

Comment: @TylerLawson, no worries. I have another question, I can only find the algorithm of sage (or Magma) which can compute the automorphism group of definite form. Is there a way that at least we can compute some X for a given K (when K is an indefinite form)?

Answer (score 3):

The following matrix $T$ will satisfy our condition:
$$ T = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -2 & 2 & -1 \\  1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$
Here is the Magma computation in case you are interested:

```
> L := LatticeWithGram(Matrix(Integers(), 4, 4, [2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 0, 0, -1, 
0, 2, 0, -1, 0, 0, 2]));
> LL := LatticeWithGram(Matrix(Integers(), 4, 4, [4, -6, 4, -2, -6, 12, -8, 4, 4, 
-8, 6, -3, -2, 4, -3, 2]));
> IsIsometric(L, LL);
true 
[ 2  1  1  0]
[-2 -2 -1  1]
[ 2  2  1  0]
[-1 -1  0  0]
```

Because of your convention you have to transpose one more time at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check Magma.

Comment: thanks again. I have another question, I can only find the algorithm of sage (or Magma) which can compute the automorphism group of definite form. Is there a way that at least we can compute some X for a given K (when K is an indefinite form)?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such functionality for indefinite forms.