# Diophantine equation about the automorphism group of lattice by constraints

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

Fixed $\sigma_x=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $K=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 32 & -64 \\
 1 & 32 & -32 \\
 -2 & -32 & 64 \\
\end{array}
\right),$

I want to find $n$ such that, $K_n=\sigma_x  \oplus \sigma_x  \oplus \cdots\oplus\sigma_x  \oplus K$.
and the corresponding $W \in GL(2n+3,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $W^{T}K_n^{-1}W=K_n^{-1},$ the only constraints for $W$ the downright corner should be $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 8 & -5 \\
 5 & 13 \\
\end{array}
\right).$ For example, if $n=1,$ I manage to find a $W$ looks like $W= \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_5 \\
d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & 8 & -5 \\
e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & 5 & 13 
\end{bmatrix} $ such that:
\begin{equation}
W^{T}K_1^{-1}W=K_1^{-1}.
\end{equation}
I try to use Mathematica and find no solutions.
Then I try $n=2$ and I still can not find the solution. But I don't know how to prove there is no solution for $W^{T}K_n^{-1}W=K_n^{-1}.$ for any $n$. I believe there should be $1$.

My comment about this problem:

1 I can not find much literature about the diophantine equation solution of integer quadratic form (at least for $4 \times 4$). But my imagination is that when $n$ grows, there should be more freedom and more variables. So one should be able to find a solution or at least prove the solution exists.

2 Since $K_n \oplus \sigma_x$ is an indefinite matrix so that there is no computational system to find that automorphism group of $K_n$. See [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381265/matrix-congruence-and-smith-normal-form) here. An indefinite matrix will lead to an infinite automorphism group so the capacity of the automorphism group should be large enough to capture such $W$.

3 Notice that the smith normal form for $=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 32 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 32 \\
\end{array}
\right). $ So for any $K_n$ it always has two nontrivial components $32$. So this is why there is a constraint for $2 \times 2$ corner for $W$.

My research has a problem related to this type of question given $K$ and $W$ (restrict $W$ for the right down corner and claim that one can find large enough $K$ (enlarge $K$ and $W$) with the same and nontrivial Smith normal ($\neq 1$) form and satisfy $W^{T}K_1^{-1}W=K_1^{-1}.$ )

Any comments and results are very welcome, thanks a lot.

Comment: Let's use simple English: what do you already know, and what are you looking for? For instance, you say that *"My claim is that I should be able to find large enough $n$ such that $K_n=\sigma_x  \oplus \sigma_x  \oplus \dots \oplus \sigma_x  \oplus K$*", but a bit further you seem to look for a matrix $W$. I'm confused.

Comment: OK, I just want to find $n$ and corresponds $W$. I change the text, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I take it that $n$ is meant to be the number of copies of $\sigma_x$ in the definition of $K_n$. But then I'm confused when you write that you managed to find $W$ for $n=1$, but Mathematica found no solutions. Also, it's not clear to me why this particular $K$ is interesting, nor why the insistence on that particular $2\times2$ lower right corner.

Comment: n is the number of pauli x, this is correct